# Is concision needed here?

Tags: word-usage

I have two question in below two sentences, which are highlighted in bold.

Q1: Is it fine to retain "***The shipping of raw materials being improved***" in the corrected version?

Q2: What is the difference between "***economical***" and "***economic***"? Please provide relevant examples to understand more.

> **Incorrect:** ***The shipping of raw materials being improved*** has become an ***economical*** factor in the transformation of Japan into a world economic power.
>
> **Correct:** ***The improvement in shipping of raw materials*** has become an ***economic*** factor in the transformation of Japan into a world economic power.

Comment: Concision is usually a good thing, but there is nothing in the grammar of the language that requires it. "being improved" becomes "improvement" since the sentence calls for a nominal, and we already have such a noun in **improvement**, so there's no need to jerry-rig one with "being" + adjective.

Comment: A *victory* here would send the team into the finals [good].   *Being victorious* here would send the team into the finals [not so good].

Comment: @TRomano Are you mentioning [not so good] as [informal]

Comment: It's not as concise.   The sentence wants a nominal (a noun or noun-like word or phrase) as the subject of *would send*.  Such a noun already exists, **victory**, so there is really no need to *assemble* a noun-like phrase such as **being victorious**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Economical* means "efficient", or "doesn't cost a lot of resources/money."  You can usually substitute the phrase "low-cost".

*Economic* means "to contribute to or having do with an economy," in the sense of boosting a country's GDP, etc.

Your first sentence does not make sense because "The shipping of raw materials being improved" is not something that answers the question "how much does this cost?" or "how many resources does this consume?" - you're just saying shipping has improved.

Your second sentence makes sense, but is awkward because it's obvious that economic factors contribute to economic power.  So it sounds like you just want to say the word "economic" as much as possible.  You don't really need the first "economic":

> The improvement in shipping of raw materials has become a factor in the transformation of Japan into a world economic power.

Comment: "an factor" to "a factor"